# Using pseudo-classes to reduce the opacity of background images but not text

Tags: html, css

So the following code works to effect the opacity of a background-image for "my-container" and not affect the opacity of "h1", which is the desired result.

HTML:

```
<div class="my-container">
    <h1>Scotch Scotch Scotch</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #5C97FF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* You could use :after - it doesn't really matter */
.my-container:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1500/1000');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Some questions regarding this code:

Why do you require 'overflow:hidden' in the .my-container class?

I find that if I change or remove any of the property-value pairs in '.my-container:before' then the background image just does not display at all. Specifically why does 'content' need to be set to ' '? 
Why must width and height both have a value? Does this need to be in %?

Thank you

Comment: Why you use `:before` and why do not set the styles to `.my-container` itself?

Comment: Because that will also affect the opacity of h1 which I do not want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

- No, overflow: hidden is not required for this effect
- pseudo elements won't be valid and not displayed if they don't have the content property set
- A pseudo element is essentially empty when it is first set so a width and height has to be set. because .my-container has position: relative set the 100% make the pseudo element which is placed before the text the same size as the container element.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a higher `z-index` to the `h1`

```css
.my-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #5C97FF;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.my-container:before {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.6;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1500/1000');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
    <h1>Scotch Scotch Scotch</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```css
.my-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #5C97FF;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1500/1000');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

div.mask{
  background-color:#5C97FF64;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
h1{margin:0;}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="mask">
    <h1>Scotch Scotch Scotch</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```